# JDeveloper CodeStyle: One Line If-Statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper, reformatting

In the Team I joined they refused to use the Code Reformat, because their code looks really ugly after using it.
I was able to improve it by customizing the Code Style of JDeveloper (our organization say, we have to use it).
But I really struggle to find a option for this problem:

we have some lines with single line if-statements, they should look like this:

```
if (someboolean) oneMethod();
```

but the code reformat always do this:

```
if (someboolean)
  oneMethod();
```

This includes several Problems:

1. less readable if there are multiple if statements

> if (list.contains(x)) myMethod("x");
>
> if (list.contains(y)) myMethod("y");

2. more possibilities of code destruction by adding a (log)line between the if and the method

   ```
   if (someboolean)
      log("if was true");
      oneMethod();
   ```
3. more lines in already long methods
4. this team is used to it since years, would confuse them if it suddenly change

I don't want to add brackets to if-statements like this, because it would fix problem 2, but make problem 1, 3 and 4 even worse.

I need an option to let the If statement in one line with the instruction if there is no bracket.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. I understand that you want one line `if` statements to **not** be changed by the _JDeveloper_ code formatter. Is that correct?

Comment: I want the JDeveloper code formatter to not split if statements without brackets into 2 lines.
Better would be when the if statements that have no brackets will become one line.
This describes problems with brace less if-statements and consider to either use brackets or don't split between if-line and code-line http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/